# Does sw-precache activation of new service worker guarantees cache busting?

Tags: javascript, offline-caching, service-worker, sw-precache, sw-toolbox

I am using `sw-precache` along with `sw-toolbox` to allow offline browsing of cached pages of an Angular app.

The app is served through a node express server.

One problem we ran into is that the `index.html` sometimes doesn't seem to be updated in the cache although other assets has been updated on activation of new service worker.

This leaves users with an outdated `index.html` that is trying to load no longer existing versioned asset in this case `/scripts/a387fbeb.modules.js`.

I am not entirely sure what's happening, because it seems that on different browsers where the `index.html` has been correctly updated have the same hash.

#### On one browser outdated (problematic) Index.html

*(cached with `2cdd5371d1201f857054a716570c1564` hash) includes:*

```
<script src="scripts/a387fbeb.modules.js"></script>
```

in its content. (this file no longer exists in the cache or on remote).

#### On another browser updated (good) index.html

*(cached with the same `2cdd5371d1201f857054a716570c1564`) includes:*

```
<script src="scripts/cec2b711.modules.js"></script>
```

These two have the same cache, although the content that is returned to the browsers are different!

What should I make of this? Does this mean that `sw-precache` doesn't guarantee atomic cache busting when new SW activates? How can one protect from this?

If these help, this is the [generated service-worker.js](https://www.manshar.com/service-worker.js) file from `sw-precache`.

**Note**: I realize I can use `remoteFirst` strategy (at least for `index.html`) to avoid this. But I'd still like to understand and figure out a way to use `cacheFirst` strategy to get the most out of performance.

**Note 2**: I saw in other related questions that one can change the name of the cache to force bust all the old cache. But this seems to beat the idea of `sw-precache` only busting updated content? Is this the way to go?

**Note 3**: Note that even if I hard reload the browser where the website is broken. The site would work because it would skip service worker cache but the cache would still be wrong - the service worker doesn't seem to activate - my guess because this specific SW has been activated already but failed at busting the cache correctly. Subsequent non-hard-refresh visits would still see the broken `index.html`.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a way to solve it without using remoteFirst?

Answer (score 2):

(The answers here are specific to the [`sw-precache` library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache). The details don't apply to service workers in general, but the concepts about cache maintenance may still apply to a wider audience.)

If the content of `index.html` is dynamically generated by a server and depends on other resources that are either inlined or referenced via `<script>` or `<link>` tags, then you need to specify those dependencies via the `dynamicUrlToDependencies` option. Here's an example [from the `app-shell-demo`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/master/app-shell-demo/gulpfile.babel.js#L126) that ships as part of the library:

```
dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
  '/shell': [
    ...glob.sync(`${BUILD_DIR}/rev/js/**/*.js`),
    ...glob.sync(`${BUILD_DIR}/rev/styles/all*.css`),
    `${SRC_DIR}/views/index.handlebars`
  ]
}
```

(`/shell` is used there instead of `/index.html`, since that's the URL used for accessing the cached App Shell.)

This configuration tells `sw-precache` that any time any of the local files that match those patterns change, the cache entry for the dynamic page should be updated.

If your `index.html` isn't being generated dynamically by the server, but instead is updated during build time using something like [this approach](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev#revmanifestpath-options), then it's important to make sure that the step in your build process that runs `sw-precache` happens after all the other modifications and replacements have taken place. This means using something like [`run-sequence`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) to ensure that the service worker generation isn't run in parallel with other tasks.

If the above information doesn't help you, feel free to [file a bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues) with more details, including your site's URL.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. The index.html is generated during build process and as you're suggesting it is the last task I run - after revision already happens (Grunt tasks). Anyhow, I thought I'd ask to see if there's something obvious happening to try and address it. I am moving to a gulp-flow and will see if after I deploy a new service worker people still sees the same problem or not. If that still happens I might just fallback to a remoteFirst approach - though this might break offline support until a new service worker has been deployed.

Comment: If you're already doing the right thing in terms of when `sw-precache` runs, then I don't think the behavior you're seeing is expected. Cache updates should be all-or-nothing, and you shouldn't end up in an inconsistent state. Could you file a bug at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues and we'll investigate there?